# How to display a wordpress user address on a specific page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create a code (By Shortcode - I know how to create shortcodes) to show the state and city of the Wordpress user on a specific page.
My problem is this: I made a WordPress site and used the woocommerce + simple auction plugin. I didn't like the layout, so I used Elementor to create a new one. Then I used ShortCodes to put everything in place. On the plugin site there are a number of native shortcodes and there is also a list of codes to create new shortcodes, among these shortcodes is one to show the name of who is winning the auction, but what I need is to show the city and state who's winning, not the name. I tried a lot, but unfortunately I have not succeeded. Can anyone help me with this?

```
// Show name of bidders (This code works fine)
add_shortcode( 'show_winning_name', 'function_show_winning_name' );
function function_show_winning_name(){
    global $product;

    $bid_count = intval($product->get_auction_bid_count());
    if(absint($bid_count) > 0 ){
        echo "<p class='show-city-winning'>";
        echo get_userdata($product->get_auction_current_bider())->display_name;
        echo "</p>";
    }
}
```

I tried several variations of this code to try to show the user's address, but none works.

```
 // Show city of bidders
add_shortcode( 'Show_city_of_bidders', 'function_Show_city_of_bidders' );
function function_Show_city_of_bidders(){
    global $product;
    global $woocommerce;
$customer_address = $woocommerce->customer->get_address();
$customer_address_2 = $woocommerce->customer->get_address_2();
$customer_city = $woocommerce->customer->get_city();
$customer_state = $woocommerce->customer->get_state();
$customer_postcode = $woocommerce->customer->get_postcode();

    $bid_count = intval($product->get_auction_bid_count());
    if(absint($bid_count) > 0 ){
        echo "<p class='monstrar-cidade-encendo'>";
        echo get_userdata($product->get_auction_current_bider())->$customer_city;
        echo "</p>";
    }
}
```

It does not display any errors, but it does not display the city either.

Comment: Looks like you need to understand basic programing concepts, First, You are using `$woocommerce->customer->get_state();` that function get the `CURRENT LOGGED USER` state, to display the data you should echo only the $customer_state variable instead of `echo get_userdata($product->get_auction_current_bider())->$customer_city;` use `echo $customer_state`. also you should be sure that the `$bid_count` validation is needed.

Comment: Very sorry. I finally understood my mistake ... And now that I realized the mistake I realized that I got it right several times, but I thought I was wrong ... My big mistake is in the name of the city I had registered for testing ... I was checking which of the address fields this function would call. And the name of the city I had put was City. So every time it worked, City came up and I thought there was a mistake. Sorry for the stupidity ...I'll fix the code, and put it down here

Comment: This code works.:
 // Show city of bidders
add_shortcode( 'Show_city_of_bidders', 'function_Show_city_of_bidders' );
function function_Show_city_of_bidders(){
    $bid_count = intval($product->get_auction_bid_count());
    if(absint($bid_count) > 0 ){
        echo "<p class='monstrar-cidade-encendo'>";
        echo get_userdata($product->get_auction_current_bider())->billing_city;
        echo "</p>";
    }
}